# Mono + embedded firebird

Tags: winforms, mono, firebird, wine

About a year ago, I was able to run a win32 application based on .Net 4.5 on my linux machine using an embedded Firebird database.

To make absolutely sure, I removed all firebird stuff on my linux server and only copied the embedded dll's as it works for windows.

When I run using MONO version 3.12.0, I get following error when trying to open a DB connection:

> Error: fbembed
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) FB_1061628003_Class:isc_attach_database (intptr[],int16,byte[],int&,int16,byte[])
>     at FB_1061628003_Class.IFbClient.isc_attach_database (System.IntPtr[] statusVector, Int16 dbNameLength, System.Byte[] dbName, System.Int32& dbHandle, Int16 parmBufferLength, System.Byte[] parmBuffer) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Native.FesDatabase.Attach (FirebirdSql.Data.Common.DatabaseParameterBuffer dpb, System.String dataSource, Int32 port, System.String database) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal:Connect ()
>     at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open () [0x00000] in :0

I read [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/firebird/) that that the firebird .Net client was not supported in later releases than 2.6.

Now that's a while back and I wanted to know if anybody had insights / updates on this particular topic?

As an alternative, does anybody know if wine of equivalent would be working?

Comment: What is the specific problem? Show the code you use and the errors you get. If you don't get errors, describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: The mono page you link to doesn't say Firebird is not supported, it instructs you to download the driver from the Firebird website (instead of using the driver that was included with mono until version 2.6).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Wine and was able to install .Net framework and I was able to connect to my database.